# Signature invalid warning in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I faced on the warning as below when I build my app in xcode.

---

### Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

In the internet, there are many people who faced on this warning,but there is no solution. ( they are searching the solution even now..)

Many of them faces on the problem after installing Xcode 4.0 beta, and somw of them is ok when they reinstall Xcode 3.2.2.

I am not finding any solution for this.

Could someone help me please..?

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using, and what version of the iPhone/iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: man, I been fighting this for the the last four days now. I did everything ever told in any forum. no luck so far. let me know if you get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Ok you may have tried this already, but this is what finally worked for me.

Created a "**Distribution**" certificate + provisioning profile in the "provisioning portal".

This allowed me to get past the codesign error you mentioned above for a Device+Release build.